# Estou com problemas no meu algoritmo em C

Tags: c

Criei uma calculadora:

```
    include stdio.h

    include stdlib.h

    include locale.h

    int main(void){

        system("color 0a");
        float num1, num2;
        char op;
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
        while(1){
        printf("\t\t\tCALCULADORA DO BARALHO\n");
        printf("Faça seus Cálculos: ");
        scanf("%f%c%f", &num1,&op,&num2);
        switch (op){
            case '+':
            printf ("\nO Resultado é= %.1f\n", num1+num2);
            break;
            case '-':
            printf ("\nO Resultado é= %.1f\n", num1-num2);
            break;
            case '*':
            printf ("\nO Resultado é= %.1f\n", num1*num2);
            break;
            case '/':
            printf ("\nO Resultado é= %.1f\n", num1/num2);
            break;
        default:
            system("cls");
            printf("\n(There something wrong DUDE!!! Try again)\n\n");
            break;
        }
        if(num1!=0 && num1!=1 && num1!=2 && num1!=3 && num1!=4 && num1!=5 && num1!=6 && num1!=7 && num1!=8 && num1!=9){
            system("cls");
            printf("(There something wrong DUDE!!! Try again)\n\n");
            system("color 0c");
            system("pause");
            break;  
        }
        else{
        }
        if(num2!=0 && num2!=1 && num2!=2 && num2!=3 && num2!=4 && num2!=5 && num2!=6 && num2!=7 && num2!=8 && num2!=9){
            system("cls");
            printf("(There something wrong DUDE!!! Try again)\n\n");
            system("color 0c");
            system("pause");
            break;
        }
        else{
        }
        printf("\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n!!!!LUCAS PRODUÇÕES E DESENVOLVIMENTO!!!!\n;-;");

        system ("pause");

        system ("cls");
    }

//use ctrl+c para fechar o programa.
    return 0;
}
```

No entanto ela apresenta os seguintes problemas:

1. Assim que uma das condições de erro é atingida o loop estabelecido
   pelo while(1) se encerra e o programa se fecha. Eu quero que ele
   volte ao início.
2. Após o primeiro cálculo dar certo, se o segundo em diante atender
   a uma das condições de erro o programa sofre um bug e não da pra
   fazer mais nada.

Comment: Se quer passar para outra iteração troque o `break;` por `continue;`. Se quiser verificar se um inteiro não se encontra no intervalo [0,9]  faça `if (num1 < 0 && num1 > 9) {/* Seu código aqui.*/}`

Comment: Eu quero verificar se o número é float, caso n seja quero q o programa sinalize um erro e volte ao começo, para o loop.

Comment: Em C não da para fazer isso. A linguagem C não passa informação do tipo em runtime.

Comment: Eu só quero q n bug quando eu digitar um caractere, apenas mande uma msg de erro e volte ao programa.

Comment: Para isso você tem que verificar o resultado de `scanf`. Em caso de sucesso `scanf` retorna o número de argumentos preenchidos, em caso de falha ele retorna 0 ou um código de erro(número negativo). [Documentação do `scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf)

Answer (score 0):

Não sei por que você limitou as operações entre 0 e 9, então eu limitei minha implementação também.

As verificações devem ser feitas antes de realizar os cálculos e caso for encontrado uma entrada invalida o programa quebra o laço atual usando o **continue**, o **break** é utilizado para encerrar o loop.

Evitei usar a função **system()** para ter portabilidade, se quiser parar o programa utilize um **getchar()** ou execute o programa pelo terminal do seu sistema ou terminal integrado da sua IDE/Editor.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("[CALCULADORA]\n");

  float n1 = 0, n2 = 0;
  char op = '+';

  while(1) {
    printf("DIGITE A OPERAÇÃO(ex: 2 + 2, pressione Ctrl + C para sair): ");

    scanf("%f %c %f*c", &n1, &op, &n2);

    if(n1 < 0 || n1 > 9 || n2 < 0 || n2 > 9) {
      printf("As entradas estão limitada entre 0 a 9. Tente Novamente...\n");
      continue;
    }

    switch(op) {
      case '+':
        printf("[RESULTADO]: %.2f\n", n1 + n2);
      break;
      case '-':
        printf("[RESULTADO]: %.2f\n", n1 - n2);
      break;
      case '*':
        printf("[RESULTADO]: %.2f\n", n1 * n2);
      break;
      case '/':
        if(n2 != 0) {
          printf("[RESULTADO]: %.2f\n", n1 / n2);
        }else {
          printf("O número %.2f não pode ser dividido por zero! Tente Novamente...\n", n1);
        }
      break;
      default:
        printf("Operação Inválida! Tente Novamente...\n");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```